# HttpPostedFileBase Could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to upload a .csv file and import to a database.  I am trying to use `HttpPostedFileBase` to accept the file as its own parameter, but I keep getting an error stating it could not be found. I checked on MSDN and it stated the namespace is `System.Web`.  I currently have using `system.web` in the controller, but the directive is not being used. When I go under Dependencies < SDK < Microsoft.NETCore.App I do see System.Web.dll in there.

Comment: Try with IFormFile interface

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

In .Net core you have to use `IFormFile` interface to capture the posted data in server side as per msdn below
The individual files uploaded to the server can be accessed through Model Binding using the IFormFile interface. IFormFile has the following structure:

```
    public interface IFormFile
    {
        string ContentType { get; }
        string ContentDisposition { get; }
        IHeaderDictionary Headers { get; }
        long Length { get; }
        string Name { get; }
        string FileName { get; }
        Stream OpenReadStream();
        void CopyTo(Stream target);
       Task CopyToAsync(Stream target, CancellationToken cancellationToken = null);
}
```

Check the link from msdn 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads